Number of lattice paths with certain properties
Consider the set $Q$ of lattice paths with $n$ steps consisting of left (L), right (R), and upward (U) steps (such a path can be regarded as a word of length $n$ over the alphabet $\{L, R, U\}$). A jump in such a path is a maximal subsequence of consecutive upward steps. E.g., for $n = 10$, the path $\text{UULUUUULRLU}$ has $6$ upward steps and $3$ jumps. Let $X = X(u, l, r, k)$ be the number of lattice paths in $Q$ with exactly $u$ upward steps, $l$ left steps, $r$ right steps, and $k$ jumps, where $1 \leq k \leq u \leq n$. Prove the following formula:
$|X| = \binom{u-1}{k-1} \binom{l+r+1}{k} \binom{l+r}{l}$
I understand how to come up with the first two expressions $\binom{u-1}{k-1}$ and $\binom{l+r+1}{k}$. Briefly explained: The former derives form a counting arrangment with $u$ unlabeled balls and $k$ labaled boxes where each box has at least one ball. The latter on the other hand derives form a counting arrangment with $n-u-(k-1)$ unlabeled balls and $k+1$ labaled boxes where the number of balls in each box is arbitrary. That being said, I do not know how to come up with the last expression, i.e., $\binom{l+r}{l}$. Any help is appreciated.

Call left and right steps "sideways" steps. The first factor is the number of ways of splitting the sequence of $u$ up steps into $k$ jumps. The second factor is the number of ways of splitting the sequence of $l+r$ sideways steps into the $k+1$ subsequences that will be placed before, after, and between the jumps, with the condition that the subsequences between the jumps must be nonempty. The last factor is the number of ways of deciding which sideways steps are $L$s and which are $R$s.

Let $G(x,y,z,t)$ be the generating function of these words where $x,y,z$ mark the number of $L, R, U$ respectively and $t$ marks the number of jumps. A word is either

empty
$L$, followed by another word
$R$, followed by another word
nonempty sequence of $U$'s, followed by an empty word or a word beginning with $L$ or $R$

This turns into a generating function equation
$$
G = 1+ xG + yG + t\frac{z}{1-z}\left(1 + xG+yG \right)
$$
Let's solve
$$
G = \frac{1+(t-1)z}{1-x-y-z - z(t-1)(x+y)}
$$
By geometric series we can write
$$
G = (1+(t-1)z)\sum_{a=0}^\infty (x+y+z+z(t-1)(x+y))^a
$$
Then let's use trinomial theorem to expand the summand $S_a$
$$
S_a = (\color{green} {x+y} + \color{red}{z} + \color{blue}{z(t-1)(x+y)})^a
\\
= \sum_{b=0}^a \sum_{c=0}^{a-b} \binom{a}{b}\binom{a-b}{c} (\color{green}{x+y})^b \color{red}{z}^c (\color{blue}{z(t-1)(x+y)})^{a-b-c} \\
= \sum_{b=0}^a \sum_{c=0}^{a-b} \binom{a}{b}\binom{a-b}{c} (x+y)^{a-c} z^{a-b} (t-1)^{a-b-c}
$$
Then let's exctract the coefficient of $x^l y^r z^u t^k$ of $G$. The prefactor $(1+(t-1)z)$ makes it so that we need to calculate two terms. Let's call $G_1 = \sum_{a=0}^\infty S_a $
$$
[x^l y^r z^u t^k] G \\
= [x^l y^r z^u t^k] G_1  - [x^l y^r z^u t^k] (1-t)z G_1 \\
= [x^l y^r z^u t^k] G_1 - [x^l y^r z^{u-1} t^k] (1-t) G_1
$$
Let's do them separately. First is
$$
w_1 := [x^l y^r z^u t^k] G_1
= [x^l y^r z^u t^k] \sum_{a=0}^\infty \sum_{b=0}^a \sum_{c=0}^{a-b} \binom{a}{b}\binom{a-b}{c} (x+y)^{a-c} z^{a-b} (t-1)^{a-b-c}
$$
Since we want the coeffiecient $[x^l y^r]$, we want to set $a-c = l+r$. The variable $z$ is already there purely, so $a-b = u$. Solving and setting these and also extracting from the binomials, yields
$$
w_1 = \sum_{a=0}^\infty \binom{a}{a-u}\binom{u}{a-l-r} \binom{l+r}{l} (-1)^{l+r+u-k-a}\binom{l+r+u-a}{k}
$$
Similarly the second
$$
w_2 := [x^l y^r z^{u-1} t^k] (t-1)G_1
= [x^l y^r z^u t^k] \sum_{a=0}^\infty \sum_{b=0}^a \sum_{c=0}^{a-b} \binom{a}{b}\binom{a-b}{c} (x+y)^{a-c} z^{a-b} (t-1)^{a-b-c}
= \sum_{a=0}^\infty \binom{a}{a-u+1}\binom{u-1}{a-l-r} \binom{l+r}{l} (-1)^{l+r+u-k-a}\binom{l+r+u-a}{k}
$$
So we have the answer $w_1 + w_2$
$$
 (-1)^{n-k} \binom{l+r}{l}  \sum_{a=0}^\infty (-1)^a \left(\binom{a}{a-u}\binom{u}{a-l-r} + \binom{a}{a-u+1}\binom{u-1}{a-l-r} \right) \binom{n-a}{k}
$$
I guess there's some magic that turns this into $ \binom{u-1}{k-1} \binom{l+r+1}{k} \binom{l+r}{l}$. At least it agrees: Desmos calculation. I'll get back to trying to prove this or if someone else can prove it...
